# How to get the element window.initialState use by beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need some advice: I have to create a Python program to scrape a website like coding by javascript.

I tried to get the element window.initialState use by beautifulsoup but it's not working; How can I get "Title" and "longURL" from this json.

this element are part of url

```
('window.initialState = {"kw":null,"originalKw":"","title":"Vitamins and '
 'Supplements","numRecordsFrom":"1","numRecordsTo":"24","numRecordsTotal":"5353","adobeRecords":[{"productVendor":"Swanson '
 'Premium","brandUrl":null,"productName":"NAC N-Acetyl '
 'Cysteine","productPartNumber":"SW854","productDetails":"600 mg 100 '
 'Caps","productPillSize":"O","productPotency":"600 '
 'mg","productDiscountPrice":"10.44","offerMaxQty":"99999","rating":4.8,"shippingWeight":0.225,"statusMessage":"In '
 'stock","statusId":"I","swansonItem":true,"tooLowToShow":false,"promoDetail":null,"bogo":false,"numReviews":"206","totalQuestions":null,"totalAnswers":null,"servingSize":"1 '
 'capsule                ","servingPotency":"600 mg                        '
 '","servings":"100       '
 '","retailPrice":"10.99","everyDayLowPrice":"10.99","percentDiscount":0.05,"outletmall":false,"discountable":true,"newWebItem":false,"vegan":false,"vegetarian":false,"kosher":false,"glutenFree":false,"organicUSDA":false,"nonGMO":false,"payPalExcluded":false,"easyRefillAllowed":true,"brandRefresh":false,"longURL":"swanson-premium-nac-n-acetyl-cysteine-600-mg-100-caps","masterGroupItem":"","flagMap":{"shoprunner":"shoprunner","highdemand":"highdemand","customerfavorite":"customerfavorite","canadanodisc":"canadanodisc"},"itemCategoriesDTO":{"breadCrumbsDTOList":[{"breadCrumbsList":[{"name":"Health '
 'Concerns","seoURL":"/view/health-concerns","searchTerm":false},{"name":"Respiratory","seoURL":"/view/respiratory","searchTerm":false},{"name":"NAC","seoURL":"/view/nac","searchTerm":false}],"topLevelKeyword":"NAC","bottomLevelKeyword":"Health '
 'Concerns","singleItem":false}]},"otherSizes":null,"numExtraXlImages":null,"reviewList":null,"suggestedAdobeRecord":null,"suggestedAdobeRecordString":null,"supFactsTemplate":false,"sfHtml":null,"catalogItem":null,"numListReviewsPages":0,"productDescriptionList":null,"bulletsList":null,"discount":0.05,"srEligible":true,"statusUnavailable":false},{"productVendor":"Swanson '
 'Premium","brandUrl":null,"productName":"Vitamin D3 - Highest '
 'Potency","productPartNumber":"SW1371","productDetails":"5,000 IU (125 mcg) '
 '250 Sgels","productPillSize":"D","productPotency":"5,000 IU (125 '
 'mcg)","productDiscountPrice":"8.95","offerMaxQty":"99999","rating":4.9,"shippingWeight":0.247,"statusMessage":"In '
 'stock","statusId":"I","swansonItem":true,"tooLowToShow":false,"promoDetail":null,"bogo":false,"numReviews":"633","totalQuestions":null,"totalAnswers":null,"servingSize":"1 '
 'softgel                ","servingPotency":"5,000 IU (125 mcg)            '
 '","servings":"250       '
 '","retailPrice":"11.19","everyDayLowPrice":"11.19","percentDiscount":0.2,"outletmall":false,"discountable":true,"newWebItem":false,"vegan":false,"vegetarian":false,"kosher":false,"glutenFree":false,"organicUSDA":false,"nonGMO":false,"payPalExcluded":false,"easyRefillAllowed":true,"brandRefresh":false,"longURL":"swanson-premium-highest-potency-vitamin-d-3-5000-iu-5000-iu-250-sgels","masterGroupItem":"","flagMap":{"highdemand":"highdemand","shoprunner":"shoprunner","customerfavorite":"customerfavorite"},"itemCategoriesDTO":{"breadCrumbsDTOList":[{"breadCrumbsList":[{"name":"Health '
 'Concerns","seoURL":"/view/health-concerns","searchTerm":false},{"name":"Bone '
 'Health","seoURL":"/view/bone-health","searchTerm":false},{"name":"Vitamin '
 'D","seoURL":"/view/vitamin-d","searchTerm":false},{"name":"Vitamin '
 'D3","seoURL":"/view/vitamin-d3","searchTerm":false}],"topLevelKeyword":"Vitamin+D3","bottomLevelKeyword":"Health '
 'Concerns","singleItem":false}]},"otherSizes":null,"numExtraXlImages":null,"reviewList":null,"suggestedAdobeRecord":null,"suggestedAdobeRecordString":null,"supFactsTemplate":false,"sfHtml":null,"catalogItem":null,"numListReviewsPages":0,"productDescriptionList":null,"bulletsList":null,"discount":0.2,"srEligible":true,"statusUnavailable":false},{"productVendor":"Swanson '
 'Premium","brandUrl":null,"productName":"Quercetin - High '
 'Potency","productPartNumber":"SW1671","productDetails":"475 mg 60 Veg '
 'Caps","productPillSize":"OO","productPotency":"475 '
 'mg","productDiscountPrice":"10.63","offerMaxQty":"3","rating":4.7,"shippingWeight":0.158,"statusMessage":"In '
 'stock","statusId":"I","swansonItem":true,"tooLowToShow":false,"promoDetail":null,"bogo":false,"numReviews":"95","totalQuestions":null,"totalAnswers":null,"servingSize":"1 '
 'capsule                ","servingPotency":"475 mg                        '
 '","servings":"60        '
 '","retailPrice":"13.29","everyDayLowPrice":"13.29","percentDiscount":0.2,"outletmall":false,"discountable":true,"newWebItem":false,"vegan":false,"vegetarian":true,"kosher":false,"glutenFree":false,"organicUSDA":false,"nonGMO":false,"payPalExcluded":false,"easyRefillAllowed":true,"brandRefresh":false,"longURL":"swanson-premium-high-potency-quercetin-475-mg-60-veg-caps","masterGr
```

```
page = requests.get(url)
soup = bsoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

script = soup.find_all('script')
pprint(script)
```

So, I try to use

```
data = re.search(r'window.initialState = {.*}', html_data)
```

but it can not convert to json

Answer (score 0):

I have taken your data   as `HTML` you can use `.string` to find text data from script tag

```
html="""<script>window.initialState = {"kw":null,"originalKw":"","title":"Vitamins and Supplements"}</script>"""
soup=bs(html,"html.parser")
data=soup.find("script").string
```

Now using `re` module find the appropriate data using expression

```
import re
data=re.findall("{.*?}",data)[0]
```

and it will return string object just load into `json` it will return key-value pair object data

```
import json
main_data=json.loads(data)
```

Output:

```
{'kw': None, 'originalKw': '', 'title': 'Vitamins and Supplements'}
```

Comment: I have apply your code and stuck with some issue now

Comment: if possible can you provide URL!

Comment: https://www.swansonvitamins.com/vitamins-supplements